# Visualize call graphs for Python

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am looking for a simple tool to visualize the call graph for Python modules (i.e. what function calls what function etc.).

It exists an abandoned package [pycallgraph](https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.io/en/master/), which does not work anymore.

Is there any other package available to can represent Python call graphs?

Comment: You probably can do something with doxygen.

Comment: It is quite simple. See the comments with your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494608/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-a-documentation-and-call-graphs-for-all-python-fi

Comment: Yes, that is my other post...

Comment: But I still have no graphical representation of e.g. where some method is called from...

Comment: I agree, Albert, Doxygen should make this simple, plus give the chance to add a lot more documentation. It is pretty much industry standard in embedded programming .

Answer (score 1):

I feel slightly guilty here for just capitalising on @MawgsaysreinstateMonica 's and @albert 's comments, which gives most of the answer, but I thought I'd just formalise it for another reader's benefit.

1. Install Doxygen.
2. Install Graphviz, and add its 'bin' directory
3. Run up Doxywizard, and select the "Call graphs" and "Called by
   graphs" options (these are unticked by default) [- ee @albert 's link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494608/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-a-documentation-and-call-graphs-for-all-python-fi for the keyword equivalents.

This produces adequate call graphs, although they seem to get confused by Python's

```
if __main__:
   pass
```

clause.  I just commented it out while producing the diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyan.py` to generate a call graph.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963321/build-a-call-graph-in-python-including-modules-and-functions) stackoverflow question for details.

```
Usage: pyan.py FILENAME... [--dot|--tgf]

Analyse one or more Python source files and generate an approximate call graph
of the modules, classes and functions within them.

Options:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --dot                output in GraphViz dot format
  --tgf                output in Trivial Graph Format
  -v, --verbose        verbose output
  -d, --defines        add edges for 'defines' relationships [default]
  -n, --no-defines     do not add edges for 'defines' relationships
  -u, --uses           add edges for 'uses' relationships [default]
  -N, --no-uses        do not add edges for 'uses' relationships
  -c, --colored        color nodes according to namespace [dot only]
  -g, --grouped        group nodes (create subgraphs) according to namespace
                       [dot only]
  -e, --nested-groups  create nested groups (subgraphs) for nested namespaces
                       (implies -g) [dot only]
```